# Hard Drive Preview / Disk Utility Used Space Discrepancy?

Tags: disk-utility, partition, storage

So I recently cleared a lot of space off of my hard drive as a sort of "spring cleaning," and I got it down to less than 40GB, but my computer doesn't seem to agree with itself on that. If I look at the info of my hard drive on my desktop, it gives me this: [image: Hard Drive Info]

but when I look at the partition in Disk Utility, it gives me this: [image: Disk Util Partition Inspection]

How do I get DiskUtil to realize how small my hard drive is?

Comment: I believe that get info excludes anything that's in your bin/trash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have Time Machine enabled? This could be a result of the Time Machine snapshots...

Have you looked at this thread here: [How to fix Disk Utility, About This Mac, and Finder that disagree on hard drive space usage?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47647/how-to-fix-disk-utility-about-this-mac-and-finder-that-disagree-on-hard-drive)

To disable Time Machine Snapshots :

Open the Terminal from Applications/Utilities
Enter : sudo tmutil disablelocal
Enter your password at the prompt

Comment: I'm not sure that it's even necessary to disable Time Machine to get this space back. I think these snapshots are only kept for at most a week and will be delete if you need the disk space anyway (for example if you try to create a large file)