# Diff between diskutility and finder on free space

Tags: disk-utility, disk-space

I came across this today :

[image]

At first I was like : "Caching bastard." but no... The finder is right and the diskutil is wrong... Why ?

Comment: Can you check whether http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70983/large-difference-in-reported-free-disk-space or http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47647/how-to-fix-disk-utility-about-this-mac-and-finder-that-disagree-on-hard-drive solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is probably that you have local snapshots of time machine backups (http://support.apple.com/en-us/ht4878). The difference is that the Finder calculates the free space you can use (the backups would be deleted if necessary). They are stored at /.MobileBackups (at least that's what it has been in Mavericks iirc) if you want to have a look and verify how much space it is consuming.

Other possible causes:

- some people claim that if you have disk encryption enabled those
  values may differ
- maybe Disk Utility was opened before you removed
  some files and didn't refresh?